# ~ and ${USER} don't work in .desktop files

Tags: 12.04, .desktop

Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

I am trying to manually create a .desktop file to launch an application. I wish to execute the command:

```
java -jar ~/.osbuddy/osbuddy.jar
```

When I run my .desktop file. However, this does not work. I then tried:

```
java -jar /home/${USER}/.osbuddy/osbuddy.jar
```

which did not work either.

Finally,

```
java -jar /home/branon/.osbuddy/osbuddy.jar
```

worked fine. I manually executed all of the above lines through the terminal and it launched the program fine. Why won't it work in a .desktop file?

Thanks for any light you can shed. This is my first time on AskUbuntu so I apologise if I'm ignoring some customary rules of this form. If I've transgressed, please correct me.

Comment: ${USER} is not valid anyways. It is `$USER`.

Comment: @Rinzwind [In situations where `$USER` is valid, `${USER}` is valid also.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (And `${parameter}` is not merely a bash-ism; see the section on "Parameter Expansion" in [`man dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/dash.1.html).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command in a `.desktop` file is not run by a shell but using some system call. Because of that you can't use shell syntax like `~` or `${USER}` there

Comment: So, to clarify: there's no way to get around using the full path in the Exec line? Thanks!

Comment: You could explicitly use a shell, like `sh -c 'java -jar ~/.osbuddy/osbuddy.jar'`. But I think using the full path is usually the better solution.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. Marked as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

[As Florian Diesch says](https://askubuntu.com/a/606881/22949), [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion) and [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is not supported in launchers (i.e., `.desktop` files). But if you need to use them--or other shell expansions--you can do so by making the launcher *execute a shell* with command-line arguments telling the shell to run a specific command and exit.

Thus you can make your command:

```
sh -c 'java -jar ~/.osbuddy/osbuddy.jar'
```

I've used `sh` (which [in Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) is [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/dash.1.html)) rather than [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/bash.1.html)) for efficiency and minimalism. But if you needed an advanced feature provided by `bash`, you could use that instead.

If the path `~/.osbuddy/osbuddy.jar` is valid for multiple users and multiple users will be using the launcher, I recommend the `sh -c` (or if you prefer, `bash -c`) way. However, if this is only for you and your main goal is to avoid typing `/home/brannon`...well, passing the command to `sh -c` involves some extra typing, too.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation -- I was woefully unaware of what    sh and     bash actually were :)